# Closed sets in ordinal spaces

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I'm dealing with intersections of closed sets in ordinal spaces and I need some help. 
If $\kappa$ is a cardinal number and $\{C_\alpha\}_{\alpha<\beta}$ are closed sets in $[0,\kappa[$ of cardinality $\kappa$, what happens with $\bigcap_{\alpha<\beta} C_\alpha$ if $\beta\geq cf(\kappa)$?

What is the supremum of the cardinals $\beta < \kappa$ such that $\bigcap_{\alpha<\beta} C_\alpha \neq \emptyset$ if $cf(\kappa)=\omega$?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question, $\beta$ is 1: any ordinal of cofinality $\omega$ has two disjoint club sets. (Take a cofinal sequence $\alpha_i$ with $\alpha_0=0$, and let $A=\{\gamma: \exists i(\alpha_{2i}<\gamma\le\alpha_{2i+1})\}$ and $B=\{\gamma: \exists i(\alpha_{2i+1}<\gamma\le\alpha_{2i})\}$.

In general, this shows that - if we define $B(\kappa)$ to be the sup of all $\beta$ such that the intersection of $\beta$-many closed subsets of $\kappa$, each of cardinality $\kappa$, is nonempty - we always have $B(\kappa)\le cf(\kappa)$. And of course - unless $cf(\kappa)=\omega$ - $B(\kappa)\ge cf(\kappa)$ and so so $B(\kappa)=cf(\kappa)$. This means that the answer to your first question is, "Such an intersection can be empty."

Comment: Thank you @user28111 ! But, if $\kappa$ is $\omega$ then the sets $P=\{2n:n\in\omega\}$ and $O=\{2n+1:n\in\omega\}$ are closed, have size $\omega$ and $P\cap O=\emptyset$. So in this case $B(\omega)<\omega$...

Comment: @Ergonvi: $\omega$ is the only exceptional case: it’s the only infinite cardinal with disjoint closed unbounded subsets.

Comment: Thank you another time to both! But @Brian M. Scott, how we can argue to ensure that the intersection of finitely many closed sets is nonempty when $cf(\kappa)=\omega$ and $\kappa\neq\omega$? That is, $B(\kappa)\geq\omega$. The other inequality is clear by the above reasoning

Comment: We can't, of course - the bad case is whenever $cf(\kappa)=\omega$, not just $\kappa=\omega$. I was being silly. :P

Comment: But, for example, when $\{\alpha_n\}_n$ is cofinal and strictly increasing $B=\emptyset$ so it doesn't have cardinality $\kappa$...

Comment: Probably @user28111 you would want to say $B=\{\gamma:\exists i(\alpha_{2i+1}<\gamma\leq \alpha_{2i+2})\}$...

Comment: Anyway I can't see why $A$ and $B$ have cardinality $\kappa$... :S

Comment: Argh, quite right, I forgot about controlling the cardinality. Since $\kappa$ is a cardinal, though, this is easy: just space out the $\alpha_i$s sufficiently (make $\vert [\alpha_i, \alpha_{i+1}]\vert$ at least $\vert \alpha_i\vert$ for every $i$). The fact that $\kappa$ is a cardinal means that for $\alpha<\kappa$, $\alpha+\vert\alpha\vert<\kappa$ as well (with $\vert\alpha\vert$ viewed as the initial ordinal of $\alpha$, that is, the smallest ordinal with cardinality $\alpha$). I think that does the trick?